# Element height issue in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created my own `tooltip` and the content based on `title` attribute and position by element `offset().top` and `left` but the problem is tooltip gained unwanted height, how can i prevent this? and why it have this? . see this example please:

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('title')) {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title');

    $(this).mouseover(function() {

      var leftPos = $(this).offset().left;
      var topPos = $(this).offset().top;

      if ($('.tooltip').length) {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
        $('body').append('<span class="tooltip">' + title + '</span>').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').css({
          top: topPos + 20,
          left: leftPos + 20
        });
      } else {
        $('body').append('<span class="tooltip">' + title + '</span>').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').css({
          top: topPos + 20,
          left: leftPos + 20
        });
      }
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background: #303030;
    font-size: 10px!important;
    bottom: -25px;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="Sampel title">Test</a>
<a title="Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title">Test2</a>
<a title="Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title">Test3</a>
```

I don't want to set certain height, and want to get height and width automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is right, except for the `bottom` property in the CSS. Combined with the top being added that's what's causing issue. So your CSS just needs to be:

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background: #303030;
    font-size: 10px!important;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Here's the updated example:

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('title')) {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title');

    $(this).mouseover(function() {

      var leftPos = $(this).offset().left;
      var topPos = $(this).offset().top;

      if ($('.tooltip').length) {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
        $('body').append('<span class="tooltip">' + title + '</span>').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').css({
          top: topPos + 20,
          left: leftPos + 20
        });
      } else {
        $('body').append('<span class="tooltip">' + title + '</span>').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').css({
          top: topPos + 20,
          left: leftPos + 20
        });
      }
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background: #303030;
    font-size: 10px!important;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="Sampel title">Test</a>
<a title="Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title">Test2</a>
<a title="Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title">Test3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set the `bottom: -25px` for the `.tooltip` div which then stretches it vertically:

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('title')) {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('title', title).removeAttr('title');

    $(this).mouseover(function() {

      var leftPos = $(this).offset().left;
      var topPos = $(this).offset().top;

      if ($('.tooltip').length) {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
        $('body').append('<span class="tooltip">' + title + '</span>').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').css({
          top: topPos + 20,
          left: leftPos + 20
        });
      } else {
        $('body').append('<span class="tooltip">' + title + '</span>').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').css({
          top: topPos + 20,
          left: leftPos + 20
        });
      }
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background: #303030;
    font-size: 10px!important;
    /*bottom: -25px;*/
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a title="Sampel title">Test</a>
<a title="Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title">Test2</a>
<a title="Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title Sampel title">Test3</a>
```